# Как узнать оригинал слов на английском языке, при автоматическом переводе Google

Tags: google-translate

На важном для меня сайте при регистрации был сгенерирован ключ, состоящий из 16-ти слов, которые должны были быть только английские, но Google их автоматически перевел на русский (причем перевел примерно половину, остальные слова остались на английском языке). По незнанию на тот момент, этот ключ был скопирован как верный. Как выяснилось, это не так. Теперь вопрос: Возможно ли узнать оригинал написания этих слов до автоматического перевода? При переводе через Google транслейт перевод получается некорректный (система сайта его идентифицирует как неправильный), я пробовала переводить и общей фразой (16 слов) и каждое слово по отдельности.
Прошу помочь! Заранее благодарна!

Comment: А у вас страница со сгенерированным текстом закрыта уже? Если нет, не закрывайте.

Comment: Страница была закрыта сразу после копирования данных...

Comment: Стойте-стойте, а _браузер_ не был закрыт? Закрытую страницу можно переоткрыть в некоторых браузерах.